# how enable SNMP on all Computer remotely?

Tags: windows-server-2003, installation, snmp

I need to find the easiest way to install snmp on all computers?
we have Windows Server 2003 with 160 Client.

Comment: what are your clients, what services are they using and what management software have you got?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer assumes you want to enable SNMP on either XP or 2003.  The Windows source directory, *i386*, needs to be configured correctly for this to work.

Create a file titled "snmp.txt" that contains the following:

```
[NetOptionalComponents]
SNMP=1
```

Run the following command to install the SNMP feature:

`sysocmgr.exe /i:%WINDIR%\inf\sysoc.inf /u:"%PATH_TO_FILE%\snmp.txt"`

This can be performed remotely via Computer Logon script or with a tool such as `psexec`.

You can use Group Policy to configure the SNMP settings.  In `gpmc.msc` look under Computer Configuration,  Administrative Templates, Network, SNMP to see the available options.

[How to add or remove Windows Components by using Sysocmgr.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=KB;EN-US;222444)

[Configure the SNMP Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa377963%28VS.85%29.aspx)